# Low Quality - wrong but not low quality

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

While reviewing low quality posts I came to an answer which is wrong (misunderstood the question) but not (really) low quality. The reasons for recommending deletion none of them matches. And I think down-voting would take care of the question, see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6490858

I hesitate to click on "Looks OK" (because in the past that leads to "pay attention") even if this is my believe there is no reason to delete it. What do you think would be the right thing to do? (and yes I can always Skip but thats I think not the point of the evaluation).

Comment: Recommending deletion for posts that don't need to be deleted, or clicking "Looks OK" for a post that's not, isn't really the point of the evaluation either.  The Skip button was put there to handle situations where the other options aren't a good fit, in your judgment.

Answer (score 34):

You don't have to be evaluating for correctness in the low quality posts queue, in fact you shouldn't be evaluating correctness.

If it looks like an ok answer to some question, then click "Looks OK"

Answer (score 9):

First off, take note that this is the "Low Quality Review Queue" - not the "Very Low Quality Flag Review Queue".  The threshold for what is low quality is much more lax than the threshold for the very low quality flag.

To that extent, the subtitle of the Low Quality review queue is:

> Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts

And the guidance within the review is:

> - **Looks OK** if nothing is wrong with this answer
> - **Edit** if you can fix all the problems with this answer
> - **Recommend Deletion** if this answer cannot be fixed and should be removed
> - **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

If this answer is indicative of the type of quality that you accept on Stack Overflow, hit "Looks Ok".  If it is something that is sub par for Stack Overflow, recommend that it is deleted.

That brings us to "what should be deleted?"  For that, we go to the [help center > Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers):

> ### Why and how are some answers deleted?
>
> Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

In this case, one could look at the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27483676/#comment43410745_27483676) on the answer in the review:

> This isn't what the OP is asking. Granted, the title could conceivably be interpreted as such, but reading the body of the question makes clear what is being asked. -- iamnotmaynard some time ago

To this, one *could* be justified as saying that this isn't fundamentally answering the question and may be removed.  Or it could be not even a partial answer to the actual question.

You would be perfectly justified casting a recommend deletion vote on that answer.

Remember to review and vote the way that leads Stack Overflow to be the site that you want to see.

Comment: Yes and I actually enjoy answers which address only partially the question but also backgrounds, common missunderstandings or simply assotiations. As long as it is not the only or high rated answer. But I guess thats not a good measure for moderating. so your last recommendation should be "remeber to review the way that leads you to accept the Stack Overflow taste of things" :)

Comment: @eckes I'd contend that it is possible for a site to change with its community. Other SE sites have done it for various directions of change. SO has a lot of inertia that can make it harder to change if that is what one wants, but if active reviewers delete more low quality posts out of the review queue the rather than "I can read it and it has code, looks ok", the site *can* start to track a different direction for quality that the status quo that it has now.