# Low Quality, but still an answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I was just browsing the Low Quality Posts review.  As far as I can see, a lot of the posts in that review queue are:

- Really terrible answers
- One line of code with no explanation
- Code that does not make sense

All of these are without a thought "low quality," but the <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd> reasons are:

[image: Deletion reason modal]

Since the type of answers mentioned above don't fit into any of the categories I end up reviewing them with <kbd>Looks Ok</kbd>.

#### My questions

I'm currently reviewing them as "Look Ok" and going to the mentioned answer and down-voting them (since they are an answer and not spam or comments). Is this the correct way to do it?

Or should I just "Recommend Deletion" and use the "No comment needed" option?

**Note**
Not dup of: [How to review low quality answers which are not crap but just incorrect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278436/how-to-review-low-quality-answers-which-are-not-crap-but-just-incorrect)
Askes what to do with answers that look good but are wrong.
Or : [Low Quality - wrong but not low quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280342/low-quality-wrong-but-not-low-quality)
Ask to what to do with wrong questions that are not low quality.

Comment: Deleting or downvoting answers that are not wrong isn't very useful.  Do look at the question first, always good odds that the answerer didn't think it was worth twenty minutes of his free time.  Best to not post to a shoddy question at all but SO users can't help themselves being helpful.  Don't underestimate the power of the Skip button btw.

Answer (score 7):

Code only answers are lower on quality scale because it is like giving a person a fish but not actually teaching them how to fish. Despite that deletion is not the only way forward because it is not quite bad enough to warrant deletion. They can still be improved provided the user is willing enough to add a good (or atleast some) explanation. So, I would say, use "Recommend deletion" only in extreme cases when it is unsalvageable.

Purpose of the review queues is not just to remove answers but to remove only those that cannot be salvaged by any means. Hence, in my opinion, the first step should be to let the user know how code only answers are unwelcome and unhelpful. You can use any one of the comments mentioned in [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers) for this purpose.

Voting is completely your choice. I would downvote it only if the code only answer is from a user who has been a member of Stack Overflow for long enough to realize that such answers are unwelcome.

Below are a few cases and how I would have treated them:

- **Answer is code only but is posted by a user who has been a member for less than a week (or) has less than 100 rep points** - Leave a comment guiding them how it should be improved. I would sometimes "Skip" the review after leaving a comment to ensure that it stays in the review queue and others can act on it or improve it if OP doesn't take any action.
- **Answer is code only, posted by an experienced user but is so concise that it can be understood even without an explanation** - Leave a comment indicating how an explanation would still help novice users in future. I wouldn't downvote here.
- **Answer is code only, posted by an experienced user and is rather complex even for a mid-level user to understand** - This probably warrants a downvote because they are experienced enough to understand why it is a bad to give such an answer.
- **Answer is code only and doesn't attempt to answer the question**  - Vote to delete it with a custom reason. There is not much point in retaining them. This doesn't apply to your question but I am mentioning it for completeness sake.

I am not saying reputation levels should always be a factor in decision making but just that new users could probably get better with some guidance.

Finally, a very welcome behavior would be to edit the answer to offer an explanation - if you have the free time and know the subject well enough to understand and explain the answer without being wrong. After all, as I mentioned earlier, the purpose of the review queues is not just to remove poor quality content from our site but also to improve the quality wherever possible.

Comment: I see, I'll take the reputation and editing in mind when dealing with low quality posts.

Comment: Not just reputation @Persijn. Just a basic check to see if the user is well aware of the site's objectives and are still giving such answers. If the user has been on the site for more than a certain length of time and/or has a certain amount of rep, they are bound to know more about how the site works and the quality that is expected.

Comment: While it is right that code-only answers generally don't qualify for deletion from review, that's not because the author could come back and add an explanation (in which case they can also undelete, no problem), but because they are actually bad but not bad enough.

Comment: I have to disagree with your last bullet point.  Even if the answer is wrong it is still an answer and should be down voted and commented on.  also see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: Exactly @Deduplicator Lower on quality but not low enough to warrant a delete unless it is wrong. That is what I intended to say too.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yeah, correct. I was meaning only the "doesn't attempt to answer" part. Will remove the offending part now :)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why my flag got declined when I flagged a code-only answer posted by a user with 1 reputation.